# Present an animated view on top of initial view controller on startup, but not any other time the initial view controller loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, startup, viewdidload

When my app is starting up I'm showing the default `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and then I'm transitioning to a view controller `StartupAnimation` containing an animation whose first frame is identical to `LaunchScreen.storyboard` so that the transition looks seamless. Then from there, I'm presenting my `HomeScreen`. This all works nice and I'm able to show the animation only on startup.

I'm wondering, however, is there's a way to make the animation contained in `StartupAnimation` a subView of `HomeScreen` so I can load the data of `HomeScreen` while the animation is finishing? In other words, can I show my animation the first time `HomeScreen` loads (during app startup) but have it hidden every other time `HomeScreen` loads?

Comment: Since you mentioned the magic words "only once" and "Objective-C", I suggest you take a look at GCD and dispatch_once https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once

Comment: I think you need to provide more details about the navigation flow in your application. What happens to the `HomeScreen` when the user leaves it? Is it deallocated or just hidden?